# Como fazer uma matriz transposta de dimensões escolhidas pelo usuário em c?

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um algoritmo que faz a transposta de uma matriz cujo tamanho deve ser escolhido pelo usuário.

Eu já escrevi um código, mas não funciona corretamente para matrizes cujo número de linhas é menor que o número de colunas.

Segue o código e um exemplo de execução do programa:

```
void matrizTransposta(int tamanhoLinha, int tamanhoColuna, int transposta[tamanhoColuna][tamanhoLinha])
{
  int linha;
  int coluna;
  int aux;
  int indice = 1;
  int tamanho;

/*
Exemplo:

{11, 12}          {11, 21, 31, 41}
{21, 22}  ---->>  {12, 22, 32, 42}
{31, 32}
{41, 42}

*/
```

Os tamanhos tamanhoLinha e tamanhoColuna são definidos na função principal, no final do código, e representam o número de linhas e de colunas da matriz inicial.

No trecho abaixo é criada uma matriz quadrada cuja ordem é o tamanho da maior dimensão escolhida na função principal. Por exemplo, se o número de linhas for maior que o número de colunas, a ordem será igual ao número de linhas (tamanhoLinha).

Em seguida, todos os elementos dessa matriz são igualados a zero.

```
  if (tamanhoLinha > tamanhoColuna)
  {
    tamanho = tamanhoLinha;
  }

  else
  {
    tamanho = tamanhoColuna;
  }

  int matriz[tamanho][tamanho];

  //*****ZERAR MATRIZ*****

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanho; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanho; coluna++)
    {
      matriz[linha][coluna] = 0;
    }
  }
```

O trecho abaixo (IMPRIMIR MATRIZ) imprime a matriz zerada. Isso não tem utilidade prática para o programa, mas ajuda a visualizar passo a passo o que ocorre no programa.

Em seguida, o usuário preenche a matriz com os elementos que deseja e por fim é impressa, com os valores já preenchidos pelo usuário.

Uma linha ou coluna ficará zerada, pois a matriz quadrada excede uma dimensão definida pelo usuário. O objetivo disso é permitir a criação da transposta mais à frente.

```
  //*****IMPRIMIR MATRIZ*****

  printf("\n");

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanho; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanho; coluna++)
    {
      printf("%d\t", matriz[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }


  //*****PREENCHER MATRIZ*****

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinha; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColuna; coluna++)
    {
      printf("\nPreencha o valor [%d][%d]\n", linha + 1, coluna + 1);

      scanf("%d", &matriz[linha][coluna]);
    }
  }

  //*****IMPRIMIR MATRIZ*****

  printf("\nMatriz inicial\n\n");

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanho; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanho; coluna++)
    {
      printf("%d\t", matriz[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }
```

Inicia abaixo a transposição da matriz. Primeiro os valores da matriz inicial são trocados, depois é preenchida uma nova matriz chamada transposta (já declarada no argumento da função), que copia os elementos da matriz inicial modificada, mas tem suas dimensões corrigidas.

Seu número de linhas é o número de colunas (tamanhoColuna) escolhido pelo usuário na função principal e seu número de colunas é o tamanhoLinha.

Assim, é igual à matriz inicial modificada, mas sem a coluna/linha zerada.

```
  //*****TRANSPOSTA*****

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinha; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColuna; coluna++)
    {
      if (linha > coluna)
      {
        aux = matriz[linha][coluna];
        matriz[linha][coluna] = matriz[coluna][linha];
        matriz[coluna][linha] = aux;
      }
    }
  }

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanhoColuna; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoLinha; coluna++)
    {
      transposta[linha][coluna] = matriz[linha][coluna];
    }
  }
```

São impressas, respectivamente, a matriz inicial alterada (sob o nome de matriz final) e a transposta.

Neste ponto é possível visualizar o problema. Quando o número de linhas escolhido pelo usuário na função principal é menor que o número de colunas, as colunas excedentes não são alteradas pela "função transposição", e os zeros na transposta não são substituídos por outros números.

Já testei o programa utilizando vários tamanhos diferentes e os resultados foram os mesmos já relatados aqui.

As imagens no final do post permitirão melhor visualização do problema.

```
  //*****IMPRIMIR MATRIZ*****

  printf("\nMatriz final\n\n");

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanho; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanho; coluna++)
    {
      printf("%d\t", matriz[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }

  //*****IMPRIMIR TRANSPOSTA*****

  printf("\nMatriz Transposta\n\n");

  for (linha = 0; linha < tamanhoColuna; linha++)
  {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoLinha; coluna++)
    {
      printf("%d\t", transposta[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }
}

//*****FUNÇÃO PRINCIPAL*****

int main()
{
  int tamanhoLinha;
  int tamanhoColuna;

  printf("\nDigite o número de linhas desejado\n");

  scanf("%d", &tamanhoLinha);

  printf("\nDigite o número de colunas desejado\n");

  scanf("%d", &tamanhoColuna);

  int transposta[tamanhoLinha][tamanhoColuna];

  matrizTransposta(tamanhoLinha, tamanhoColuna, transposta);

  return 0;
}
```

Imagem 1:

[image: Quando tamanhoLinha > tamanhoColuna, o programa funciona corretamente]

Imagem 2:

[image: Quando tamanhoLinha < tamanhoColuna, o problema aparece]

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está transpondo a matriz *in-place*, então a ordem das operações passa a fazer diferença. Quando você transpõe a primeira metade da matriz, você deixa de ter a primeira metade da matriz original. Neste caso, você tem que trocar os dois valores `[i][j]` e `[j][i]` *ao mesmo tempo*. A parte relevante do código é:

```
//*****TRANSPOSTA*****

for (linha = 0; linha < tamanho; linha++) {
    for (coluna = linha + 1; coluna < tamanho; coluna++) {
        aux = matriz[linha][coluna];
        matriz[linha][coluna] = matriz[coluna][linha];
        matriz[coluna][linha] = aux;
    }
}

for (linha = 0; linha < tamanhoColuna; linha++) {
    for (coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoLinha; coluna++) {
        transposta[linha][coluna] = matriz[linha][coluna];
    }
}
```

Aqui nós percorremos todas as células à **direita** da diagonal principal (não precisamos transpor a diagonal principal, claro) e trocamos cada célula com a correspondente do outro lado da diagonal. Mas temos que fazer isto para **toda a matriz expandida `tamanho×tamanho`**, não somente para a parte `tamanholinha×tamanhoColuna` da matriz.